# Cron and delayed_job - using both in tandem for Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cron, delayed-job

Am I right in thinking the most efficient way to run a background process every 2 hours on heroku (e.g. sending emails / stats collection etc.) is to use a cron, scheduled for every two hours, that then sticks items in a delayed_jobs queue (based on the dj gem) that is then picked up by a heroku worker instantly?

Further to that, once the app is in production, am I right in thinking the cost-effective approach would be to have hirefire spin up a worker to carry out the job and then shut it down afterwards?

Are there other approaches I should consider? I have not done this kind of delayed job work before - in development and in basic production testing before go live I have it all based on a heroku cron - but in production that doesn't seem sensible if the load on the cron job increases.

Any pointers on worthwhile alternative approaches appreciated!

Comment: +1 for "hirefire". I hadn't heard of that before. Your idea to use cron + DJ seems sensible enough to me. I'm not sure what you mean by "load on the cron job" though, since presumably all it's doing is queuing up DJ tasks.

Comment: I meant the load on cron *now*, when cron actually carries out the big task, rather than just placing things in the queue. I.e. I'm just using a cron task to fire a class method. Really I should be only using cron to push things to the queue. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I think we're talking about the same thing. Cron should load the queue (which should be a very lightweight thing for it to do). DJ jobs should perform the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hirefire is definitely the way to go if you don't have a full time set of work for a worker to do as you'll be paying for a dormant worker otherwise.

Another option for the timing is to get the delayed job to reschedule itself when it completes using the :run_at argument that's available.  The worker will then do it when it's hit the time (although I've never tested this would work with Hirefire as I think they just look at Job count)

It's a pretty sound approach overall, and what I would use.